# Empty Access_logs

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, nginx, logging

nging vhost file: nginx works as a reverse proxy

cat /etc/vhosts/website.info

```
server {
          error_log /var/log/nginx/vhost-error_log warn;
          listen 1.2.3.4:80;
          server_name website.info www.website.info;
          access_log /usr/local/apache/domlogs/website.info-bytes_log bytes_log;
          access_log /usr/local/apache/domlogs/website.info combined;
          root /home/website/public_html;
          location / {
          location ~.*\.(3gp|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|wmv|avi|asf|asx|mpg|mpeg|mp4|pls|mp3|mid|wav|swf|flv|html|htm|txt|js|css|exe|zip|tar|rar|gz|tgz|bz2|uha|7z|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|pdf|iso)$ {
          expires 7d;
          try_files $uri @backend;
          }
          error_page 405 = @backend;
          add_header X-Cache "HIT from Backend";
          proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4:8081;
          include proxy.inc;
          }
          location @backend {
          internal;
          proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4:8081;
          include proxy.inc;
          }
          location ~ .*\.(php|jsp|cgi|pl|py)?$ {
          proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4:8081;
          include proxy.inc;
          }
          location ~ /\.ht {
          deny all;
          }
        }
```

Then

```
ls -la /usr/local/apache/domlogs/website.info-bytes_log
/bin/ls: cannot access /usr/local/apache/domlogs/website.info-bytes_log: No such file or directory
/bin/ls: cannot access bytes_log: No such file or directory

ls -la /usr/local/apache/domlogs/website.info
-rw-r----- 2 root website 0 Jan 29 03:32 /usr/local/apache/domlogs/website.info
```

the access_logs are empty for some reason.

Now under Apache I saw this:

```
#CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/website.info combined
#CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/website.info-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
```

Could that be the issue as all the customlogs under apache got commented out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If yo use nginxcp best solution it's remove and reinstall.

I think it's bug.

On latest server with latest RELEASE of Cpanel same problem.

After uninstall & reinstall all work fine.

It's a poor solution, but it's solution for me.

Comment: I'm currently on 34.1.7 as well. Is it a CPanel bug?

Comment: I think no. Just remove and reinstall nginxcp and work perfectly